# Question about error while hooking APK using Cydia Substrate JAVA API

Tags: java, android, hook, error-code, xposed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvNwW.png)
Hooking with the above code was successful.

Hooking failed because the argument value of a was not entered. I wonder why it failed

Comment: Please do not post code in form of an image.

Answer (score 0):

i solved
Resolved by lowering the version of android studio
Previously version 3.6.2, downgraded version was 2.3.2

It was not available in 3.6.2 and instant run disable.

```
provided 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82'
provided 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources'
```